# How to associate a socket.id to an array item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to make a chat-room where connected users' names are displayed in an 'Online Users' section.

The code below will add each users' name to an array and display the contents of the array.

However, if a user leaves, their username isn't removed from the array. If I pop the array, it'll likely not remove the correct username.  This makes me think I should, somehow, associate the socket-id with the username given, and create a disconnect event that removes the correct username from the array, and displays the updated version of the array. How could I alter this code to incorporate this?

script.js:

```
var user = user;
if (!user) {
  user = prompt('Please choose a username:');
  if (!user) {
    alert('Your name has been set to "Anonymous"');
    user = "Anonymous"
        items.push(user);
  } else {
      alert('Your name has been set to "'+ user +'"');
  } 
}

socket.emit('theitems', user);

socket.on('theitems', function (data) {
      $('.dispUser').html(data);
      console.log(data);
    });
```

server.js:

```
var newitems = [];
server(socket('theitems', ctx => { newitems.push(ctx.data); console.log(ctx.data); ctx.io.emit('theitems', newitems); }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that on user connection you update your array of users with new user, something like:

```
let users = [];

sockets.on('connection', socket) => {
    // This is the user associated with a new socket connection. 
    // User that you will need to remove when connection is closed.
    const user = { /* create your user */ };
    users.push(user);

    // Then you can subscribe to socket disconnect event
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        users = users.filter(u => u !== user); // removing disconnected user

        // And then here you can notify your front-end with an updated users array
    });
});
```

Comment: I actually managed to solve this for myself by emptying the array when a user disconnects and immediately sending connected name's back. Thanks for your time, though!